# How to dynamiclly change css colors in an array

Tags: css, arrays, vue.js

I want to have the data come back in the array and change colors according to if its "resolved" "working" or "open" the current code is working but is only ever one color, console log shows its coming back as resolved but my guess is its just showing the last in the array and not looping through, i tried creating a for loop in the computed and no change. I have a feeling its some small dumb detail i'm overlooking. The main function is working as i want it to, it's just the css im struggling with. Any help would be appreciated, i've found a ton of v-bind information for onclick but not any for dynamic values in an array.

```
<template>
<div
              class="card-content has-background-dark has-text-light"
              id="ev-card"
              v-for="item in p3data.slice(0, 19)"
              :key="item.p3data"
              :class="cardColor"
            >
</div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
  data() {
    return {
      p3data: [],
      status: "",
    };
  },

computed: {

    cardColor: function() {
      var color = "";
      if (this.status == "Resolved") {
        color = "green";

      } else if (this.status == "Working") {
        color = "yellow";

      } else if (this.status == "Open") {
        color = "red";

      } else {
        color = "red";

      }
      return color;

    }
  },

created() {
    var p3 = "some url";
    axios.get(p3).then(response => {
      // pulls the info from the api to display in an array
      this.p3data = response.data;
      // console.log(response.data);
      // shows the parent arrays length
      var updateInfo = response.data;

      for (var item of updateInfo) {
        var updateData = item.updates;
        var uLength = updateData.length;
        uLength = uLength - 1;
        for (var i = 0; i < updateData.length; i++) {
          // console.log(utem)
          if (updateData[i].message === "") {
            updateData[i].message = item.message;
            continue;
          } else {
          }
        }
        item.message = updateData[uLength].message;
        item.updatekind = updateData[uLength].updatekind;


        if (item.updatekind == 3) {
          item.updatekind = "Resolved";
        } else if (item.updatekind == 2) {
          item.updatekind = "Working";
        } else if (item.updatekind == 1) {
          item.updatekind = "Open";
        } else {
          item.updatekind = "Open";
        }


      }
        this.status = item.updatekind;
</script>
```

```
<style>
.red {
  border: 4px solid hsl(0, 94%, 51%);
}
.yellow {
  border: 4px solid hsl(54, 76%, 54%);
}
.green {
  border: 4px solid hsl(115, 81%, 35%);
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that your computed property, cardColor, changes only based on the value of this.status, which is a single variable specific to this component. In your code, after you do the axios call, loop through all the items and after that you do `this.status = item.updatekind` which sets status with item.updatekind, where item is the last element in the loop. And that's the status value that is used to set the cardColor property.

What you need is to calculate the cardColor for each one of your items. There are a few ways to do so, I think the most straightforward for you would be to do it in the existing code, here:

```
if (item.updatekind == 3) {
  item.updatekind = "Resolved";
  item.cardColor = "green";
} else if (item.updatekind == 2) {
  item.updatekind = "Working";
  item.cardColor = "yellow";
} else {
  item.updatekind = "Open";
  item.cardColor = "red";
}
```

and then in your template you can do

```
<template>
  <div
        class="card-content has-background-dark has-text-light"
        id="ev-card"
        v-for="item in p3data.slice(0, 19)"
        :key="item.p3data"
        :class="item.cardColor"
        >
  </div>
</template>
```

If you don't want to change the code in the promise, you can use conditional classes as well.

```
<template>
  <div
    class="card-content has-background-dark has-text-light"
    id="ev-card"
    v-for="item in p3data.slice(0, 19)"
    :key="item.p3data"
    :class="{
      'green': item.updatekind === 'Resolved',
      'yellow': item.updatekind === 'Working',
      'red': item.updatekind === 'Open'       
    }"
  ></div>
</template>
```

I guess it just depends on your personal preferences.

Thanks,

Comment: You are awesome! that did it, thank you for the explanation as well, I've only been in for 3 weeks so i'm still getting a hold of the logic.

Comment: No problem. I love Vue, you'll love it too!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how vue works nor what are you trying to achieve. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you are trying to have several cards with different colors right? If so, it seems like you are saving just one value in status, what I think it may work it would be having the cardColor function as a property of the item. And have something like :class="item.cardColor()" which would return its class based in the current state.